# How to do smooth frame interpolation and extrapolation using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, opticalflow, extrapolation, spatial-interpolation

My source data files are weather radar images captured every 15 minutes.
I'm trying to make a smooth interpolation of intermediate frames and I'm trying to extrapolate the motion onwards from the last measurement.

So far, my method has been to calculate a dense optical flow field(cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback) from two consecutive images and then to interpolate(cv2.remap) frames using optical flow and the first image. I have also made a dummy motion extrapolation using the same method.

On the [example video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6KnAsWrCSl3cDk4QW44d3FOMG8/view) you can see the caveats of this method, during the interpolation there is noticeable discontinuation between the interpolated frames and measured ones and on the extrapolation part(starts at 8s)  a full psychedelia sets in. I have tried smoothing out the optical flow field and it had a small effect, but the result stayed basically the same.

I would like to have some guidance on what methods to study next and also are there any opencv specific solutions to this kind of problem.

Question one: How to make the interpolation smoother?
Question two: Whats the correct way to do the time extrapolation of motion?

Comment: Could you provide an example of your data, cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback, and cv2.remap process?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same question.